# Datasource for multiple UItableViews in a single UIview

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I am a novice ios programmer.currently i am working on a ipad specific project.In this project a needed some custom drawing.So i  made a subclass of `UIview`, made the necessary drawing in `drawRect` method and load that `UIView` subclass via `loadView` method in the `UIViewController`. Till now this have been ok.Right now what i am trying to do is to make some dropdown list in my `UIview` subclass. For this I followed very basic approch.I made a button and and placed a `UITableView`just beneath it.The `UITableView` remains hidden at the time of loading.But when the user touch the button the `table view` shows up and shows the data in the cell fetched from an array .I have been able to do this also.

What I couldn't do is making this same thing happen for multiple `UITableView`.for another `table view` i made thing like this...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
     arryData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Samsung",@"HTC",@"Apple",nil]; //data for first table
     parameterData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Tax Expenses",@"Pretax amount",@"assets",nil]; //data for second table
     tabletableForComany.dataSource = self;
     tableForComany.delegate = self;
     tableForParameter.delegate = self;
     tableForParameter.dataSource = self;
}
```

after implementing others delegate and datasource method when I run the program i got the exception

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData _updateSectionRowDataArrayForNumSections:]
```

I think i have a problem in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    }

// Set up the cell...

   if(tableView.tag == 1)
   {
     cell.textLabel.text = [arryData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     return cell;
   }

   else if (tableView.tag == 2)

   {
    // Set up the cell...
      cell.textLabel.text = [parameterData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      return cell;

   }
}
```

when i set only one table's `datasource` i got no error but also no data shown in any of the table cell.
A help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your problem, being unable to do so. It would look like your problem lies somewhere else. That assertion failure (which, by the way, lacks documentation) would suggest a problem with either your number of sections and/or number of rows for section. Could you maybe paste your code for those as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out yourself already there seems to be a problem to have one datasource/delegate for multiple UITableViews.

I don't know enough about the internal workings of UITableViews to explain the assertion failure but I think a good solution would be to use multiple datasources and delegates, one for each table view. This approach is described in multiple stackoverflow posts, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858554/ipad-more-than-one-uitableview-in-the-same-screen/11789681#11789681) one should give you an idea.

If statements as in your code a generally considered a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is a elegant way to clean up your code. And as a bonus I expect it to solve your problem as well.

Comment: Clearly there shouldn't be a problem with having one datasource/delegate for multiple UITableViews, otherwise, if it was not an intended design, why would apple have the tableview pass itself as an argument? I'll tell you why, to support a single class being delegate/datasource for multiple tableviews.

Comment: You have a point here. I just wanted to give my view on it, it is up to shishir123 if he wants to implement my solution and probably have it working soon or if he wants to investigate further to learn more about the inner workings, costing him more time but leaving him with a deeper understanding.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies somewhere else, but still in his own code, not in the inner workings of UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning the number of rows properly in data source method `numberOfRowsInSection:`

Ref [What does the iOS error "request for rect of invalid section" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734496/what-does-the-ios-error-request-for-rect-of-invalid-section-mean)