# UITableView.RectForHeaderInSection causes 'Request for rect of invalid section' Exception, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on implementing custom headers for a UITableView in addition to the ones already available in the UITableView class (So that we can have both a title header and a subtitle header floating at the top together).

In order to do so, my table is divided in many sections which can either be:

- A title section, which is actually a section with an empty UIView as a header (since I want my custom header to float over that empty view).
- Or it can be a subtitle section, which is a normal section that uses the header provided by iOS (the one that already float at the top when we scroll).

Both type of sections can have rows within them and the implementation works perfectly until I try it with 2 custom headers.

When I try adding a second custom header, I get this exception when calling the `UITableView.RectForHeaderInSection` method :

> NSInternalInconsistencyException: request for rect of header in invalid section (6)

The thing is that I call `this.UITableView.RectForHeaderInSection(6)` and, when the exception pops up (on the exact same line), I can see that my table has at least 7 sections and that, therefore, the 6th section shouldn't be invalid.

I'm using `RectForHeaderInSection` to place my floating header where it should be.

Does anyone have an idea why it crashes even though the section isn't supposed to be invalid? Or maybe another way of getting the exact frame where i need to put my floating header (which would be the frame of the empty table view header that I created in the title sections)?

I only found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734496/what-does-the-ios-error-request-for-rect-of-invalid-section-mean) that may relate to my problem, but I don't think the source of the problem is the same in that case.

**Edit:** I realized that, when I say that the number of sections should be 7, it is the number of sections in the UITableViewSource subclass and not the 'actual' sections in the table. Could it be possible that section are removed or just never added even though they are added to the Source? How can i see the number of sections in my table other than looking at the list we have in the source?

I will probably post a part of my code tomorrow, because right now I am aware that there's not enough information to find where the problem can be.

**Edit 2:** Here's what the code looks like:

```
// first we create the custom header (Title)
var title1 = new CustomHeader();

var section1 = this.Table.TableSource.AddSection();
section1.HeaderView = title1.View;
// Fill section 1 with rows...
var section2 = this.Table.TableSource.AddSection();
// Fill section 2 with rows...

// We create the list of sections that our Title will contain
var title1Sections = new List<TableSection>();
title1Sections.Add(section1);
title1Sections.Add(section2);

// Now we call the method that will create our custom header
this.Table.TableSource.AddHeader(title1.View, title1Sections, this.Table.TableSource.Sections.IndexOf(section1);
```

so with this, we have section 1 which has a custom title header that floats over section 1 and 2. And section 2 that has a normal subtitle header which will float under the title header when they bump into each other. Now the AddHeader method:

```
public void AddHeader(UIView headerView, List<TableSection> sections, int indexOfFirstSection)
{
    RectangleF rectForHeaderInTableView = this.TableView.RectForHeaderInSection(indexOfFirstSection); /* CRASHES HERE */
    // Code that uses rectForHeaderInTableView to make our custom header float over everything...
}
```

If I only have one custom header like this, the app runs fine and there's no crash. But if I add more sections (lets say sections 3-4)the same way I did here and add a custom header, when it will try to add the second custom header, the app will crash when trying to get rectForHeaderInSection. If i decide not to have a custom header for section 1-2 and instead have one for 3-4, it still works. As long as I only have one custom header, the app doesn't crash.

Comment: "since I want my custom header to float over that empty view" I don't understand this statement. Why would you want to create a custom header view that floats above an empty header view? Why not have the actual header be a custom view?

Comment: Because when the actual header is going to encounter another header, it's going to be bumped out of the view, but I want it to float and have the other header (if the other one is a subtitle one) float under it too.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks. Will take a look when you post code.

Comment: Apparently, calling AddHeader for all the sections only at the end solves the problem! Because, before, I was calling it right after creating the sections I needed. So it would be like:
-> add section 1, add section 2 
-> add title header for 1-2 
-> add section 3, add section 4 
-> add title header for 3-4, 
And apparently that would make the app crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right, "Could it be possible that section are removed or just never added even though they are added to the Source?". They were not added in the table.

You have to call:

```
ReloadData()
```

on your tableView to sync the source with the table's data to prevent an invalid section index.