# iOS app crash in main.m

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

I encountered a crash problem that bothered me for several days.
Here's log:

```
request for rect at invalid index path ( 2 indexes [0, 0])
(null)
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x31fc33ff  + 186
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x39cbe963 objc_exception_throw + 30
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31fc329d  + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x32899fa3  + 90
    4   UIKit                               0x33e03087  + 242
    5   UIKit                               0x33e20901  + 112
    6   UIKit                               0x33f8a703  + 46
    7   UIKit                               0x34159b73  + 342
    8   UIKit                               0x33ef513b  + 3698
    9   UIKit                               0x33f0e525  + 124
    10  UIKit                               0x33eefc61  + 128
    11  UIKit                               0x33eb73a1  + 392
    12  UIKit                               0x340a4163  + 46
    13  UIKit                               0x33ddb883  + 218
    14  UIKit                               0x33dda2cd  + 1164
    15  UIKit                               0x33de51e7  + 766
    16  UIKit                               0x33de4db3  + 90
    17  UIKit                               0x33dd28e1  + 380
    18  UIKit                               0x33dd21ef  + 6198
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x35aea5f7  + 590
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x35aea227  + 34
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x31f983e7  + 34
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x31f9838b  + 138
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x31f9720f  + 1382
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x31f0a23d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x31f0a0c9 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x35ae933b GSEventRunModal + 74
    27  UIKit                               0x33e262b9 UIApplicationMain + 1120
    28  MyApp                             **0x3635** MyApp + 9781
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x3a0ebb20  + 0
)

dSYM UUID: 6DB60E5E-B047-38A9-91CC-5A42AC012288
CPU Type: armv7s
Slide Address: 0x00001000
Binary Image: CafeCar
Base Address: 0x00016000
```

I locate 0x3635 with dYSM,but it shows the bug appears in main.m:17.
Someone could help?

**Update:**
main.m(defalut):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CCAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CCAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Notice, when I first install it from Xcode to my iPhone,it stops in main.m, only the first run.Crash logs above comes from online app.I've no idea whether the two have something to do with each other.

**Update:**

Actually,I have added breakpoints before.And I am sure at least the program hasn't come into  application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method for I set NSLog there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share main.m code.

Comment: ya it will be good if you share code

Comment: Set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C exceptions" add see where it is hit.

Comment: If it is for UITableview then refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734496/what-does-the-ios-error-request-for-rect-of-invalid-section-mean)

Comment: Might be your error is not in main.m it's occur form some where else and it's not possible to track the error, so better set a breakpoint for all exceptions and see for where it's crashing.....

Comment: @DeveloperRoadies The program has not come into my delegate code yet when it crashes.

Comment: @MartinR Now see updates above please.

Comment: @LeeWong does this occur on an empty app?  If not, that would be evidence that the problem lies in your code.

Comment: @Vinz did you really think the error was in main.m or was that sarcasm? :D

Comment: @LeeWong: The backtraces and screen shots do not help so far. All uncaught exceptions will be displayed in main.m. Did you set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C Exceptions", as suggested above?

Comment: @MartinR ye,exactly.I found other bugs except this one.

Comment: @danh It's hard to say.If I use Xcode, it occurs only on the first install.If I download the app from App Store,it doesn't occur.But my crash report service reports the bug, showing thar it occurs in a fair amount of people's app, regardless of their OS or devices

Comment: From my perspective, the best clue in the post is the index path.  Once I see that, knowing I have table views, I stop digging around in assembly, and find a way to reproduce with either a simulator or a phone hooked up to xcode running my source.  I break on exceptions, and all over in my datasources.  Maybe you found an obscure bug in ios or iphone hardware, but I'd work on the more probable first.

Comment: Index path 0,0 is invalid happens on an empty table.  Tables are often empty on first install.  I'd grep for scrollToRectAtIndexPath, etc.

Comment: @danh ye,It's really weird since the bug occurs before my codes run.Notice that 'request for rect at invalid index path' which my crash-reporting-service reports comes from the app already in App Store.So it may not be reproduce locally.

Comment: @danh Will it be possible to occur before'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' method in Delegate.m?

Comment: That seems unlikely.  What evidence do you have that it's happening that early?  Maybe your code is running and the crash happens too fast for the reporting service to post?

Comment: @danh I have NSLog in it locally.But I have no idea about the online version.

Comment: Similar, and most likely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734496/what-does-the-ios-error-request-for-rect-of-invalid-section-mean

Comment: @Malaxeur But I can't catch the bug code even I set the break points.